# How to wrap an Iterator in an Iterable for re-use in a pythonic way?

Tags: python, iterator, iterable

#### Intro

I have an iterator, for example:

```py
from itertools import product

iterator_ = product([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9])
```

If i try to iterate over the iterator more than once, I won't be able, because it is exhausted after the first iteration is done.

#### Question

How can I produce an iterable `iterable_` from `iterator_` so that I can iterate over the iterator as many times as I want? Preferably, an efficient and pythonic way.

#### Ugly solution / example

**It does not work for all iterators - see the comment**

So far, I was able to come up with the following ugly solution:

```py
from copy import copy
from typing import Iterable, Iterator


class WrappedIterator(Iterable):
    """
    Wraps an iterator in an iterable

    This allows to iterate over a given iterator more than once. Subsequent
    actions on the given iterator do not have impact due to internal copying.
    """

    def __init__(self, iterator: Iterator):
        self._iterator = copy(iterator)

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator:
        return copy(self._iterator)

    def __next__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError(
            "One is not supposed to iterate over this object. Instead, "
            "one should produce an iterator from it with `__iter__` and "
            "iterate (as in, call `__next__` on the returned iterator).")
```

So that the following allows me to create an iterable out of an iterator:

```py
iterable_ = WrappedIterator(iterator_)

# The following does not fail
for _ in range(666):
    assert len(list(iterable_)) > 0

# The following fails on attempt number 1
for i in range(666):
    assert len(list(iterator_)) > 0, f"Failed on attempt {i}"
```

#### Other ideas

I saw some posts on `itertools.tee` or `itertools.zip` but I'm not sure that those solutions can be efficient and pythonic enough. But I could for sure be wrong about them.

Comment: Your `copy` solution isn't generalizable to all iterators.  Try it on a generator function `def g(): yield 1` for example: `copy(g())` -> `TypeError: can't pickle generator objects`.  I think your only real option is `tee`.  The problem is that there is no "efficient" way of doing what you want. To "replay" an iterator, you have to record the values it produces, which is essentially the same as just reading it into a list. If you're only handling generators that always return the same results, you can do the call to create the iterator inside `WrappedIterator.__iter__` on demand.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Thanks for pointing out the problem! (you probably should have posted it as an answer). Are you basically saying that unpickleable iterators can only be "copied" by using `tee` (as in, going through the values and storing them in memory for later replay) or by letting `WrappedIterator` know about the generator function so that `WrappedIterator` can generate a new iterator when needed?

Comment: I'm not sure a generic solution is possible (short of just storing the whole thing in a list, which is obviously not always possible). The generator protocol is independent of what's actually generating the data on the back end, but "restarting" the generator is going to be very dependent on that.